# Xamarin.iOS Build - Access to path "/de" is denied

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono

I have created a new Build Configuration (Test) in Visual Studio for Mac, and if I build the project with this config, I get a build error:

> Access to the path "/de" is denied.  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00071] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:114 
>     at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x000a4] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:78 
>     at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CreateDirectoryIfRequired (System.String name) [0x00027] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:224 
>     at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String dest, System.Boolean create_dir) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:248 
>     at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFileWithRetries (System.String source, System.String dest, System.Boolean create_dir) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:232  (RehaThese)

Here is the full Build Output:

```
RehaThese.iOS (Test|iPhone) wird erstellt

Build started 22.09.2017 11:53:15.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.Portable/SharpLibrary.Portable.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target PrepareForBuild:
    Configuration: Test Platform: iPhone

Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

Target _GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "_GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because its outputs are up-to-date.
Done building project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.Portable/SharpLibrary.Portable.csproj".

Build succeeded.
 0 Warning(s)
 0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.0807850

Build started 22.09.2017 11:53:15.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target PrepareForBuild:
    Configuration: Test Platform: iPhone

Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
Skipping target "GenerateSatelliteAssemblies" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "_GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target _CoreXamlG:
No input files were specified for target _CoreXamlG, skipping.

Target CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target XamlC:
    Compiling Xaml

Assembly: obj/iPhone/Test/RehaThese.dll
    ReferencePath:  ../../packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.231/lib/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll;../../packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.231/lib/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll;../../packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.231/lib/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll;/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.Portable/bin/iPhone/Test/SharpLibrary.Portable.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/mscorlib.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/Microsoft.CSharp.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Collections.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.ComponentModel.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Core.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Globalization.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.IO.Compression.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.IO.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Linq.Expressions.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Linq.Parallel.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Linq.Queryable.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Linq.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Net.Http.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Net.Primitives.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Net.Requests.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Net.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Numerics.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.ObjectModel.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Reflection.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Runtime.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Security.Principal.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Text.Encoding.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Threading.Tasks.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Threading.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Windows.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Xml.Linq.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Xml.Serialization.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Xml.XDocument.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.Xml.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/System.dll;/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile111/mscorlib.dll
     Module: RehaThese.dll
      Resource: RehaThese.lang.LanguageResources.resources... skipped.

    No compiled resources. Skipping writing assembly.

Target DeployOutputFiles:
    Creating directory '/de'
    Copying failed. Retries left: 0.
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Access to the path "/de" is denied.  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00071] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:114 
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x000a4] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:78 
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CreateDirectoryIfRequired (System.String name) [0x00027] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:224 
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String dest, System.Boolean create_dir) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:248 
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFileWithRetries (System.String source, System.String dest, System.Boolean create_dir) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:232 
Task "Copy" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "DeployOutputFiles" in project     "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project     "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese/RehaThese.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets (DeployOutputFiles target) ->

    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Access to the path "/de" is denied.  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00071] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:114 
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x000a4] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:78 
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CreateDirectoryIfRequired (System.String name) [0x00027] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:224 
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String dest, System.Boolean create_dir) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:248 
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyFileWithRetries (System.String source, System.String dest, System.Boolean create_dir) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Copy.cs:232 

 0 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.2243140

Build started 22.09.2017 11:53:15.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.iOS/SharpLibrary.iOS.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target PrepareForBuild:
    Configuration: Test Platform: iPhone
    MakeDir Task
      Directories:
        bin/iPhone/Test/
        obj/iPhone/Test/

Target _DetectAppManifest:
    FindItemWithLogicalName Task
      Items: <null>
      LogicalName: Info.plist
      ProjectDir: /Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.iOS
      ResourcePrefix: Resources

Target _DetectSdkLocations:
    DetectSdkLocations Task
      TargetFrameworkIdentifier: Xamarin.iOS
      TargetArchitectures: ARMv7, ARM64
      SdkVersion: 10.3
      XamarinSdkRoot: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current
      SdkRoot: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
      SdkDevPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
      SdkUsrPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
      SdkPlatform: iPhoneOS
      SdkIsSimulator: False

Target _BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
No input files were specified for target _BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions, skipping.

Target _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
No input files were specified for target _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions, skipping.

Target _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets:
No input files were specified for target _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets, skipping.

Target _CoreCompileImageAssets:
No input files were specified for target _CoreCompileImageAssets, skipping.

Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
No input files were specified for target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets, skipping.

Target _CoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
No input files were specified for target _CoreCompileSceneKitAssets, skipping.

Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
No input files were specified for target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases, skipping.

Target _CoreCompileTextureAtlases:
No input files were specified for target _CoreCompileTextureAtlases, skipping.

Target _CollectBundleResources:
    CollectBundleResources Task
      BundleResources:
      OptimizePropertyLists: True
      OptimizePNGs: True
      ProjectDir: /Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.iOS
      ResourcePrefix: Resources

Target _CoreOptimizePngImages:
No output files were specified for target _CoreOptimizePngImages, skipping.

Target _CoreOptimizePropertyLists:
No input files were specified for target _CoreOptimizePropertyLists, skipping.

Target _CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles:
No input files were specified for target _CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles, skipping.

Target _PackLibraryResources:
    PackLibraryResources Task
      BundleResourcesWithLogicalNames: <null>
      Prefix: monotouch

Target CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Copy Task
      DestinationFiles:
        bin/iPhone/Test/SharpLibrary.Portable.dll
        bin/iPhone/Test/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
      DestinationFolder: 
      OverwriteReadOnlyFiles: False
      Retries: 0
      RetryDelayMilliseconds: 0
      SkipUnchangedFiles: True
      SourceFiles:
        /Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.Portable/bin/iPhone/Test//SharpLibrary.Portable.dll
        /Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.Portable/bin/iPhone/Test/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
      UseHardlinksIfPossible: False

Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

Target _GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "_GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target DeployOutputFiles:
    Copy Task
      DestinationFiles: <null>
      DestinationFolder: bin/iPhone/Test/
      OverwriteReadOnlyFiles: False
      Retries: 0
      RetryDelayMilliseconds: 0
      SkipUnchangedFiles: True
      SourceFiles:
        obj/iPhone/Test/SharpLibrary.iOS.dll
      UseHardlinksIfPossible: False
Done building project "/Users/danielmartin/ownCloud/Programming/SharpLibrary/SharpLibrary.iOS/SharpLibrary.iOS.csproj".

Build succeeded.
 0 Warning(s)
 0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.3165860

--------------------- Fertig ---------------------

Erstellen: 1 Fehler, 0 Warnungen
```

If I build the Project in Debug, it compiles just fine. I checked the settings inside the project configuration and it seems like all are the same as in Debug. Does someone know what is causing this error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Delete the related data in bin/ , then have a try again.

Comment: I did a lot of things and something helped, so I am not sure if your suggestion was the fix, but yes, thanks for your help!